# How to access Azure DevOps API through VSCode extension using Azure Account extension credentials

Tags: azure-devops, vscode-extensions

I'm looking for a way to use DevOps REST API (e.g.: download artifact published from pipeline) from VSCode extension (from TypeScript/JavaScript). (That is, I'm writing the extension/code to do that...)

In VSCode there is Azure Account extension (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account) which is used in many existing extensions interacting with Azure so I'd like to use it too to be consistent. It handles Azure sign-in and exposes credentials.

I found out there is Azure DevOps Services REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and Node.js client (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api) but it seems to use different form of authentication for Azure (personal access tokens), so I think it's not possible to use it with Azure Account extension?

Is there a way to get required credential information from Azure Account, or is there an alternative for accessing things like pipeline artifacts?

Comment: Have you read into this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/runs/artifact?view=azure-cli-latest
It makes me think you might want to reinvent something already out there. Not exactly the same as a vscode extension, but well usable within vscode / ps console. And some vscode extensions do exists for azure.